# Regex in c# for allowing numbers and alphabets

Tags: c#, regex

I  am trying to write a regex that allows different set of inputs.

first 9 characters should be numeric  - 123456789

10 character is optional and if present should be Alphabet - 123456789A

11 Character if preset should be aplphanumeric - 123456789AA or 123456789A1

12 - 14 Character if preset should be numeric - 123456789AA123 or 123456789A1123

I tried this but it is not working..

```
 string sMatch = "^[0-9]{9}([a-zA-Z])\?{1}([0-9A-Za-z])\?{1}([0-9])?{1}([0-9])\?{1}$";
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(sMatch);
```

Comment: I don't think you can put `{1}` right after `?`, the question mark already matches 0 or 1 occurrence of an expression.

Also, you can simplify your expression by specifying IgnoreCase when creating the Regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know c#'s regex implementation but how about:

```
\d{9}[a-zA-Z]?[a-zA-Z0-9]?\d{0,3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
string sMatch = "^(?i)\\b\\d{9}[a-z]?[^\W_]?\\d{0,3}\\b$";
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/cX5nI6)

Answer (score 0):

A.  You need to put an '@' character before the first quotation mark in the string to mark it as a string literal so it handles \? properly.

B.  I'd break it up into a few statements, IE:

```
string preset1 = @"^[0-9]{9}", preset2 = @"[a-zA-Z]{1}", preset3 = @"[0-9A-Za-z]{1}", 
    preset4 = @"[0-9]{3}$";
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, preset1){
    //Do fits first preset
    if (Regex.IsMatch(input, preset1 + preset2){
        //Do fits second preset
        if (Regex.IsMatch(input, preset1 + preset2 + preset3)){
            //Do fits third preset
            if (Regex.IsMatch(input, preset1 + preset2 + preset 3 + preset4)){
                //Do fits fourth preset
            }
        }
    }
}
```